# Do different CUDA-capable cards really have different priority ranges?

Tags: cuda

The CUDA Runtime API documentation [tells us](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-runtime-api/group__CUDART__DEVICE.html) that the priority range might be 0-0 if the device doesn't support priorities. But - do different devices actually have different priority ranges?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Currently (CUDA 8, through pascal, subject to change in the future), for [stream priorities](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#stream-priorities), CUDA devices support:

- (Devices with CC <= 3.0) A single possible priority, priority 0.
- (Devices >= CC 3.5 ) Two priorities, -1 and 0.

The following code can be used to probe this:

```
#include <iostream>

int main(){

int priority_high, priority_low;
cudaDeviceGetStreamPriorityRange(&priority_low, &priority_high);
std::cout << priority_high << "," << priority_low << std::endl;
}
```

Note that according to the [documentation](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-runtime-api/group__CUDART__DEVICE.html#group__CUDART__DEVICE_1gfdb79818f7c0ee7bc585648c91770275), lower numbered priority values are considered higher priority, so a stream priority of -1 is higher priority than a priority of zero.

Streams are a [per-device concept](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#stream-and-event-behavior), so naturally stream priorities are only effective within the kernel launches associated with a particular device.

Comment: I do know how to probe, I just don't have lots of cards to probe (e.g. no Teslas).